# MUI React, Minimum Date

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui

How can I set Minimum Date, so the user can't pick *To Date* that is before *From Date*.
Here is my Two Date Pickers, using `moment` to format the date.

```
                                <DatePicker
                                    value={fromDate}
                                    label="From Date"
                                    color="primary"
                                    inputFormat="DD/MM/YYYY"
                                    onChange={(fromDateValue) =>
                                        setFromDate(moment(fromDateValue).format('DD-MMM-YYYY', moment.ISO_8601))
                                    }
                                    renderInput={(params) => <TextField {...params} size="small" margin="dense" sx={{ width: 238 }} />}
                                />

                                    <DatePicker
                                        value={toDate}
                                        label="To Date"
                                        color="primary"
                                        inputFormat="DD/MM/YYYY"
                                        onChange={(toDateValue) => setToDate(moment(toDateValue).format('DD-MMM-YYYY', moment.ISO_8601))}
                                        renderInput={(params) => (
                                            <TextField {...params} size="small" margin="dense" sx={{ width: 218 }} color="primary" />
                                        )}
                                    />
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the [`minDate`](https://mui.com/api/date-picker/#props) prop:

> Min selectable date.

You can add it to your second `DatePicker`, like:

```
minDate={fromDate}
```

([Working example](https://codesandbox.io/s/basicdatepicker-material-demo-forked-n4hcr?file=/demo.js))

Comment: You can see a working example added to my question

Answer (score 0):

```
      const currentDate = new Date();
      const minDate = currentDate; // Current date
      const maxDate = addDays(currentDate, 30); // max date (30+ days)
    
      const dateObj = new Date(minDate);
    
      const year = dateObj.getFullYear();
      const month = String(dateObj.getMonth() + 1).padStart(2, "0");
      const day = String(dateObj.getDate()).padStart(2, "0");
    
      const formattedDate = `${year}-${month}-${day}`;
    
      const dateObj1 = new Date(maxDate);
    
      const year1 = dateObj1.getFullYear();
      const month1 = String(dateObj1.getMonth() + 1).padStart(2, "0");
      const day1 = String(dateObj1.getDate()).padStart(2, "0");
    
      const formattedDate1 = `${year1}-${month1}-${day1}`;


     <LocalizationProvider dateAdapter={AdapterDayjs}>
                  <DemoContainer components={["DatePicker"]}>
                    <DatePicker
                      label="Date"
                      sx={{
                        backgroundColor: "rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.30)",
                        borderRadius: 2,
                        border: "1px solid",
                        borderColor:
                          showError && !selectedDate ? "red" : "initial",
                      }}
                      showDaysOutsideCurrentMonth
                      value={selectedDate}
                      onChange={handleDateChange}
                      minDate={dayjs(formattedDate)}
                      maxDate={dayjs(formattedDate1)}
                    />
                  </DemoContainer>
                </LocalizationProvider>
```

Comment: You should add explanation.

Answer (score 0):

```
import { givenDateAndCurrentTime } from "date-fran";
const stringdate = `${year}-${month}-${day}`

  <DatePicker
   format="dd/MM/yyyy"
   minDate={givenDateAndCurrentTime(stringdate)}
   value={props.values[props.fieldName]}
   label="Arrival date"
  />
```